# Has anyone managed to connect to s3 using SAS Enterprise guide v6.1?

Tags: amazon-s3, sas

Wondering can anyone help me with something. I am working for a client who uses SAS EG V6.1 It's old and crap. In newer versions there is an s3 connector built in however this one only has a http proc. I am wondering has anyone managed to connect to s3 using this?

I have tried this but ran into an issue where I need to sign the request using sha256.... However this sad version doesn't even have that.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What's the SAS version underlying? Find that with 'proc product_status; run;'.

Comment: Suppose the answer is yes, someone has managed to connect. What do you once you've received that answer? If the thing you would do next is post a different question, post *that* question now instead of asking whether a person has managed to do a thing. (Remember, Stack Overflow questions are not supposed to start a conversation.)

Comment: Does your client have `proc s3`? This is used to send and retrieve files from s3. It was added in 9.4M4.

Comment: No @StuSztukowski it is 9.3m